# Sequel pro - Importing CSV file: Encoding error

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, encoding

Sometimes, when you try to upload a CSV file that was exported from an excel sheet on Windows, you might get this error:
"File Read Error: An error occurred when reading the file, as it could not be read using the encoding you selected (Auto-detect - Unicode (UTF-8)). Only 23,000 rows were imported."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to fix this, Switch the encoding to "Western - Windows Latin 1". You can do that in the first window that opens when you want to pick the CSV file.

Comment: DO THIS ON IMPORT -- I was trying to alter the database table. Not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph El Khoury said, to avoid this problem you can switch to "Western - Windows Latin 1" but, sometimes, the problem happens again.
So you have to switch back to "Autodetect".